# Definition uniform continuity

Tags: uniform-convergence

Suppose $U_{n}^{}:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
Suppose also that $U_{n}$ uniformly converges to $l(x)$.

I know that the following definition hold:

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N:\forall n>N,\forall x \in [a,b]:|U_{n}(x)-l(x)|<\epsilon.$$

But my book uses this one:

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N:\forall n>N,\forall x \in [a,b]:|l(x)-U_{n}(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}.$$

Where does this come from?
Thanks

Comment: They are effectively the same definition, the second one may be given to be easier to solve certain problems where one would cancel out $b-a$ or something. Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, the factor of $\frac{1}{b-a}$ doesn't really matter in the definition since $b-a>0$. And of course, $$|l(x)-U_n(x)|=|U_n(x)-l(x)|$$

Comment: Thanks!, As you said we use that to cancel out b-a. A little bit further we have $\int_{a}^{b}|U_{n}{}(x)-l(x)|dx$ This should be $< \frac{\epsilon(b-a)}{b-a}$ Are they just seeing $|U_{n}{}(x)-l(x)|$as a constant ?

Comment: $|U_n(x)-l(x)|$ is not constant in the definition of uniform continuity, because you don't fix an $x$ for uniform continuity like you would for regular continuity. It has to hold for a fixed epsilon, and all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: How is the integral $<$ $\epsilon (b-a)$?